# Accessibility with unseen label

Tags: html, css, ios, iphone, accessibility

I have a couple things on my sight where it’s seen to normal sight users. But I have a hidden label that has css styling to hide it from sight users ie height 0 weight 0 line hight 0 etc. the issue is that when dragging a finger on iPhones neither options are accessible. I’m trying to find a way to make the visible content still say nothing but screen readers say something else. Thanks.

EDIT
I apologize I was very drunk when I wrote that.
I’m just going to ask a whole new question. Thanks for everyone who tried to help lol

Comment: since We don't have code that you have already worked with, If you need to make pages cater to to both visual based and assisted technology based audience then you most definitely need to use ARIA rules  a W3C standard and deal with specific issues you are facing. a quick example here https://css-tricks.com/why-how-and-when-to-use-semantic-html-and-aria/

Comment: u will need something like `aria-label='text'`, `aria-hidden=false`

Comment: I would think that Style="Display:none" should do the trick.

Comment: SO posts can be read by managers to evaluate individuals for promotions or new jobs. With that in mind, consider one more edit to your question to trim out extraneous information.

Answer (score 1):

Setting width/height to 0 isn't a correct way to hide something for sighted users while  keeping it readable for screen reader users.
Entire questions and articles on the web are devoted to explain how exactly to do it the right way.

The basic technique is called visually hidden text.
If you are using a framework, you already have predefined CSS classes like .sr_only, .visually-hidden, etc.
Here's for example the one I use, taken from knacss with a minor change of my own:

```
.visually-hidden {
position: absolute !important;
border: 0 !important;
height: 1px !important; 
/* width: 1px !important; /*Disabled because of JFW+firefox bug, all words are concatenated */
padding: 0 !important;
overflow: hidden !important;
clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
left: -2px !important;
top: auto !important;
}
```